# getElementbyClassName not shown

Tags: javascript

I´m using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getInfo() {
var myElement = document.getElementbyClassName("contentMiddle");
alert(myElement.ClassName)
}
</script>
```

When i´m clicking on the button now:

```
<input onclick="getInfo" type="button" value="ClickMe" />
```

In the body is the div class="contentMiddle"> with a table inside. But nothing is shown when i´m clicking on the button.

Comment: It returns array of elements and is not cross browser compatible

Comment: There is also a mistype in function name getElement[s][B]yClassName

Comment: is is `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: And also `myElement.className`.

Comment: always open the console(f12 on most browsers) and see for errors. You will notice that getElementByClassName is undefined method. getElementsByClassName is the one you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `getElementsByClassName` *not* `getElementByClassName`. i.e. Get Elements not Element. Unlike id of an element classname does not have to be unique for the document. There could be many elements with the same class name and function returns all of them.

It returns an array of all the elements with that class name. If you need to access a certain element you need to use the index.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function getInfo() {
      var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName("contentMiddle");
      if(myElements != null)
      {
          alert(myElements[0].className);
      }
      else
      {
          alert("No elements found !");
      }
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input onclick="getInfo()" type="button" value="ClickMe" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it´s still not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What does it alert you?

Comment: If i´m clicking on the button nothing happens. No mistake is shown.

Comment: @user2800148: show a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Change your onclick to `onclick="getInfo()"` with the brackets.

Comment: Still not working, here is the example how it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/E24ZL/2/

Comment: You still have a typo in your fiddle. It's getElementsByClassName you have a lowercase b i.e. byClassName when it should be ByClassName => http://jsfiddle.net/hDV2t/1/

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra: Yeah just noticed it should be `ByClassName` not `by` in the middle...

Comment: Thanks thats was it. But why just the name of the class is shown "contentMiddle" and not the content of the class?

Comment: Well, className returns name of the class not the content of the class.

Comment: @Kaf, it's teaching not helping. If I were you I would have gave up already.

Comment: Thanks kaf and get yourself an ice cream gdoron...

Comment: @user2800148, you don't understand, you will learn only if you'll teach youself, if you'll come here asking all the time(like you had something like 4-5 mistakes here) you will never learn. this is what we call [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and it's really for your good.

Comment: Just remember: javascript is case sensitive and built-in functions are in Camel Notation.